# ios - how to have Multiple lines of NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

There are 3 UIlabel in my TableViewCell.xib.One of them need to set attributedText with NSMutableAttributedString,the code like this:

```
NSString * htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"将订单状态从 %@ 改变为 %@ ，原因：%@",lb.order_status,lb.changed_status,lb.remark];
NSMutableAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
style.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
style.lineHeightMultiple = 0;
[attrStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
             value:style
             range:NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length)];
[attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Roman" size:13.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length)];
lbRemark.attributedText=attrStr;
```

Question 1:
 lbRemark cannot display with multiple-lines, but if I do not use NSAttributedString to set lbRemark then it can display with multiple-lines.Is there something wrong with NSAttributedString?

Question 2: I need my Cell to calculate it's height with lbRemark' height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iOS8, you don't need to calculate the height of the label. Auto-layout will do that for you.

Attach top and bottom constraints between the UILabel and the cell - do not set a height constraint for the UILabel.

In the viewDidLoad: method of your UIViewController, just do the following (replace the 50.0f with the default height of your rows):

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0f;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: Thank u for answer but it doesn't work...  I still wang to know if I Attach top and bottom constraints between the UILabel and the cell ,need I to set a constraint for the label like thie 'Height >= 14'?And Since iOS8 I can use Auto-layout to calculate height for label or cell without any codes?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to have that "Height >= 14" constraint for your label. Just set your top, bottom, leading & trailing. Set numberOfLines to 0 (or whatever maximum you want). Then add the two lines above. The cells will then be the correct height to show the full label.

Comment: Many UIView subclasses have intrinsic constraints based on their content. You need to set constraints to position the label within the cell on top, bottom, left and right but not to set the height or width. Also, you should make sure these constraints are set to priority 999 not 1,000… tableview inserts its on 1,000 constraints. Finally, you probably need to implement the row height estimate function to activate autolayout… just return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Comment: Both of u are right.@siburb @Steven Fisher . Thank u. And I finally not set  constraints height and width,just top,bottom,left and right,both priority 999 and 1000 can work good. And two codes are necessary:self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0f;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

Comment: Oops. I had a typo in my comment: tableview inserts its **own** 1,000 constraints. (The idea is that if your constraints ever contradict the ones required by tableview, you want yours to break not tableview's. And if they have the same priority, you'll see debug log and/or an exception.)

Comment: Oh oh I see.I often met degug log last month.And the conflict constraint always was 'Height >= ...'. Is my understand right? If the label's constrains to position less than the tableview's,the label can change after cell change?

Answer (score 0):

1: Set this for multiple lines:

> lbRemark.numberOfLines = 0;

2: This is how to calculate height of label according to text:

```
NSString * htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"将订单状态从 %@ 改变为 %@ ，原因：%@",@"test",@"test1",@"test2"];
NSMutableAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
style.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
style.lineHeightMultiple = 0;
[attrStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                value:style
                range:NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length)];
[attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Roman" size:13.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length)];
lbRemark.numberOfLines = 0;
CGRect paragraphRect = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(625, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                             options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                             context:nil]; //here 625 is width of label, use whatever your width

NSLog(@"height = %f", paragraphRect.size.height); //it should be height for label
lbRemark.attributedText=attrStr;
```

Comment: Thank u for ur answer but it doesn't work,the label display like this:"bla bla bla...". It still can't break lines but appear "..." in the trail.

Answer (score 0):

Hum...finally I got a solution for it.It's not anything wrong with NSAttributedString.I implement a function(my workmate who often helped me offer it )：

```
static UITableViewCell *sizingLogCell = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

if ([indentifier isEqualToString:@"logCell"]) {
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sizingLogCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indentifier];
    });

    sizingLogCell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(tableView.bounds));
    [sizingLogCell setNeedsLayout];
    [sizingLogCell layoutSubviews];
    [self configureLogCell:sizingLogCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGSize size = [sizingLogCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height + 1;
}
```

The function's name is :
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath indentifierForCell:(NSString *)indentifier

The most important thing is 'size.height ***+ 1***',if without '+1' label still can not display with multi-lines.